# In SSAS cube related Query

Tags: sql

i am a junior software developer . I am stuck at one point that my client want to add 8000 roles in its cube with filter condition on branch name.

For example .

1. Mumbai sales person can only access Mumbai data .
2. Gujarat sales person can access only Gujarat data.

like wise 8000 city are there. IS there any way to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add row filters to your dimensions. It works great but since you have to add 8000 roles, I will advise you to edit the cube code not using GUI (right click - view code). **Always make a backup of your code before editing it this way**, it's easy to mess it up and won't open again.
I strongly recommend you to install BIDS Helper in order to aid you with maintaining roles.